# Nested Should query(OR) inside a Must query(AND) in elastic Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have elastic Search data in following format:

```
{
    "is_cricketer": 1,
    "name": "Abraham",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "stellenbosch" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
},
{
    "is_cricketer": 1,
    "name": "Abraham",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "Rustenburg" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
},
{
    "is_cricketer": 0,
    "name": "deVilliers",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "Cape town" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
}
```

I need to query elastic search to get all the profiles with `is_cricketer` = `1` and an OR query over the field for `cities.name` and `name` field. ie

```
( profile.is_cricketer == 1 && (profile.name == 'Abraham' || profile.cities[i].name == 'Nelspruit' ))
```

To get the profiles with OR query on the fields `cities.name` and `name` field for matching query string is as follows and it works a expected:

```
"should": [
    {
        "nested": {
            "path": "cities",
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Nelspruit",
                    "fields": [
                        "cities.name"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "Abraham",
            "fields": [
                "name"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And the Must query to get all the profiles with field `is_cricketer` = `1` is follows:

```
{
    "must": {
        "match": {
            "is_cricketer": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Above both queries working fine and i am trying to combine both query as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "is_cricketer": "1"
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "cities",
                        "query": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "Nelspruit",
                                "fields": [
                                    "cities.name"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Abraham",
                        "fields": [
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

which is not returning expected results, its returning all the profiles with  `is_cricketer  = 1` without filtering for `name` and `cities.name`.

I also tried to include the `should` query inside must query as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "is_cricketer": "1"
                }
            }, {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "cities",
                            "query": {
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "Nelspruit",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "cities.name"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "Abraham",
                            "fields": [
                                "name"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But i got following error for the above query:

> "Error: [parsing_exception] [should] query malformed, no start_object
>   after query name, with { line=1 & col=64 }
>       at respond (/GitRepo/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:307:15)
>       at checkRespForFailure (/GitRepo/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:7)
>       at HttpConnector. (/GitRepo/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:159:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.bound (/GitRepo/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)"

How to combine both the queries to get desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why you use a multi_match query?

Comment: I am new to elastic search and i am trying out  hit and trial to get response. i can also use `query_string` there is no problem with it. for now i am facing issue at combining above must and nested should queries.

Comment: that is because you don't close the squared bracket in the must clause

Comment: No, in the second one you open the squared bracket in must clause, and you close in should clause. If the first one works, why you don't try to put all in must clause? In effect traslating it in SQL you should write ever with AND operator

Comment: Can you update and show me what's wrong here with this query here in this gist [link](https://gist.github.com/KarthikGangadhar/36456b986fa8b678d8f3378ec437589f).

Comment: Ok, i try to build it. Can you tell me the datatype of cities.name? It is keyword or text? Later i will explain you better

Comment: The datatype of cities.name Is `text`

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Abraham"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "is_cricketer": {
              "query": "1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cities",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "cities.name": {
                  "query": "Nelspruit"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: sorry for the late answer, has "is_cricketer" a text datatype? Seems not according your first output when appears without brackets

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i think you didn't read it properly. i am trying to get profiles based on this condition `if( profile.is_cricketer === 1 && (profile.name === 'Abraham' || profile.cities.name === 'Nelspruit' ) )`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me on ES 6.0.

## Setup

```
PUT test1
{
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "cities": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test1/type1
{
    "is_cricketer": 1,
    "name": "Abraham",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "stellenbosch" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
}

POST test1/type1
{
    "is_cricketer": 1,
    "name": "Abraham",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "Rustenburg" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
}

POST test1/type1
{
    "is_cricketer": 0,
    "name": "deVilliers",
    "cities": [
        { "name": "Cape town" },
        { "name": "Nelspruit" },
        { "name": "East London" }
    ]
}
```

## Query

```
GET test1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "is_cricketer": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": {
              "value": "Abraham"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cities",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "cities.name.keyword": {
                  "value": "Nelspruit"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Results - 2 hits

```
 "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 2.2685113,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "zgcesWIBVwCaLf8KSuDi",
        "_score": 2.2685113,
        "_source": {
          "is_cricketer": 1,
          "name": "Abraham",
          "cities": [
            {
              "name": "stellenbosch"
            },
            {
              "name": "Nelspruit"
            },
            {
              "name": "East London"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "eAQesWIBbxh35CpKckEH",
        "_score": 2.2685113,
        "_source": {
          "is_cricketer": 1,
          "name": "Abraham",
          "cities": [
            {
              "name": "Rustenburg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Nelspruit"
            },
            {
              "name": "East London"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 29):

if you want a should query inside a must  you can use it in the following way

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                ... your query here
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```